# passing a dictionary to all templates using context_processors

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-1.9

I want to show my notification to all my templates. In my settings I have:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'helpers.views.notifications' ,
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

helpers/views.py

```
def notifications():
    notifications =  {'A':'aaa' , 'B':'bbb' }
    return {'notifications': notifications }
```

I get nothing in my template - what am I doing wrong? 
in template :

```
{{notifications.A}}
```

Comment: Please show your view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `TEMPLATES` setting looks ok. In your context processor, you don't need to use `RequestContext`. Just return a dictionary. If you are using Django 1.9 or earlier, you **must** call the method `request.user.is_authenticated()` otherwise `request.user.is_authenticated` will always evaluate to True.

```
def notifications(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():  # Use request.user.is_authenticated for Django >= 1.10
        notifications  = {'default: 'logged in', ... }
    else:
        notifications =  {'default':'not logged in', ...}
    return {'notifications': notifications }
```

Then in your tempalate, you can access `{{ notifications.default }}`

Comment: thanx , what you're suggesting is exactly what i did in the first place(before  adding RequestContext like my current code ) and i did it again with no result , so i got suspicious may be it's something else ... i put a wrong address in my settings.py i got no error ... so i removed `TEMPLATES` option  from settings.py all together still  app is working with no error !! do i nedd to active it or something ? (i've added versions to my question)

Comment: Your `TEMPLATES` setting looks ok. You haven't shown your view as I asked, so the problem could be there.

Comment: no im saying it works fine even if i remove `TEMPLATES` from settings or put a wrong address in it isn't that weird ? i've updated my code

Comment: I don't think that removing `TEMPLATES` from your settings will help you debug the problem. If you remove `TEMPLATES` then I believe that Django 1.9 assumes that you are using the legacy `TEMPLATE_` settings.

Comment: @hretic are you running on Django's dev server or Apache/nginx etc? If the latter you might need to restart the process for the changes to take effect

Comment: @4140tm im in the localhost using django internal server

Comment: Try restarting the server anyways, if you haven't. I can't think of another reason everything to be fine if you remove `TEMPLATES` altogether